# Change the style of chapters (sections) of the .pdf document from rstudio with knitr package LATEX "titlesec"

Tags: titlesec, knitr, rstudio, rmarkdown

I try to style the chapters (sections) of an article document (documentclass: article) using the latex titlesec package, but I don't get any results, I mean that when I configure the document there is no change.

In the YAML header of rmarkdown

```
header-includes:
## Style Chapter - package "TITLESEC"
  - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  - \usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
```

Outside the YAML header

```
<!-- TITLESEC - Estilo CAPÍTULOS -->
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thesection\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
```

In the .tex file the code of the chapter (section):

```
\hypertarget{name-section}{%
\section{Name Section}\label{name-section}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}) that we can compile that shows your problem. Why should you expect us to try and assemble what you have done from your snippets? --- GOM

Comment: sorry. the document is very long. I thought it was enough. I don't want to cause any inconvenience to anyone. I thought it could be a common configuration problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted,  there are no chapters but sections in an article document class. Therefore, it's funny that you try to redefine a command  that does not exist. On the other hand, it is not clear to me what are you trying to do with `\titleformat`, but I guess that you are searching for some like this:

[image: mwe]

```
---
docummentclass: article
output:
  pdf_document: 
    number_sections: yes
header-includes:
- \usepackage{titlesec, xcolor, lipsum}
# \titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before-code}[after-code]
- \titleformat{\section}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thesection\hspace{20pt}\textcolor{gray!75}{|}}{20pt}{}
---

# Introduction
\lipsum[1][1-5]

# Objectives
\lipsum[1][6-9]
```

Comment: I used your code above and got a big space between all chapter title words

Comment: @MarkDavies With Rstudio and TexLive this example produces what you see here, that have no chapters (article documents have no chapters without a special tunning). Therefore,  seems that you are not using only my code but something else,  and that is your problem but that only you know. So what could I tell you more?

Comment: Thanks. I have asked a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707695/increasing-section-headings-for-pdf-output-using-titlesec-in-bookdown-package