# Increasing font size for section headings using titlesec in rmarkdown bookdown package

Tags: sectioning, pdf, fontsize, rmarkdown

I would like to increase the font size of my chapter titles. I am producing a pdf using `bookdown` package in `rmarkdown`. I have followed this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620762/change-the-style-of-chapters-sections-of-the-pdf-document-from-rstudio-with-k), but I get the result that my chpater headings are now spread across the page with large gaps between words.

This is my code:

````
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: false
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lmodern}
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
- \usepackage{titlesec}
- \titleformat{\section}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thesection\hspace{20pt}}{20pt}{}
mainfont: Times New Roman
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
geometry: "left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
---
\center
Title page contents

\raggedright
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}

# Preface {.unlisted .unnumbered}
Preface contents

\newpage

``` {=latex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

# Chapter 1 Heading

## First sub-section

# Another example chapter heading
````

And here is result:

[image]
[image]

How can I increase the font size of my chapter (level 1 section) headings without causing all section titles to have added spaces between words?

Comment: To me, those headings look more like they are right and left justified, when realistically, the headings should be `\raggedright`. I don't have access to the `titlesec` manuals right now, but I would suggest adding `\raggedright` just after (or before) `\Huge\bfseries` in the title definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is is always a good idea  use `keep-tex` to know what are you doing really in LaTeX.
2. You have not chapters  here, you are making  article-like   documentclass (`scrartcl`) that have no chapter but sections as first header level and trying to simulate the  book format. Suggestion: switch to a book-like document class.
3. You are trying to use Times New Roman and Latin Modern Roman together. Times is strongly discouraged in this site, and I have not this font, so the example is set to Latin Modern.
4. The geometry changes are just to crop the height of screeshot (irrelevant for the issue).
5. Finally, but not less important, The issue is caused by:

```
    \center % <--- This is the problem 
    Title page contents
    \raggedright
```

But you can make better you title page in this way:

[image: MWE]

````
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: false
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep-tex: yes
header-includes:
- \pagenumbering{roman}
- \usepackage{titlesec}
- \titleformat{\section}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thesection\hspace{20pt}}{20pt}{}
mainfont: Latin Modern Roman
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
geometry: paperheight=14cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=.5cm,bottom=1.5cm
---



```{=tex}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\Huge Title page contents
\end{titlepage}
```
# Preface {.unlisted .unnumbered}
Preface contents
    
``` {=tex}
\newpage
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```
# ~~Chapter~~ Section 1 Heading

## First sub-section

# Another ~~chapter~~ section heading

## Second sub-section
````